# Jquery Hide by Name as a Selector

Tags: jquery, hide, selector

I would like to ask if how to hide a specific field using its name. For example:

`<input type="text" name="when_is_escrow_set_to_close" class=" regular-text"   value="" />`

I want to hide this field. In normal jquery with id and class we hide it by:

`$('.classname').hide();`

But how to use the same query when we need to call the selector by name.

Thanks

Comment: This is a **very** basic question. Sufficient information is provided in the always-useful [jQuery API documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/) I suggest you start there.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've been away in programming for sometime and this below comments perfectly answered my query just in time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("input[name='when_is_escrow_set_to_close']").hide();
 //^^^selectortype^^^^^attribute name="attributevalue"
```

reference **[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

Answer (score 3):

You need [Attribute  Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7kce8/)**

```
$('[name=when_is_escrow_set_to_close]').hide();
```

**Description:** Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.